# How do OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens work?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I've been reading abount using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for the authentication process in a MEAN stack web app. I've been following [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-mean5/) tutorial, but I got confused when it comes to the refresh tokens.

I do understand that those tokens are used to get a new access token for the user once it has expired, as explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-mean5/index.html#tokens) and in any other OAuth tutorial about thos tokens, but what I don't understand is how the server knows which refresh token must be used if the user hasn't provide any credential (it is supposed to provide the credentials just the first time is logging in).

Can anyone help me with this to fully understand how this works?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization Server issues the first refresh token after the user has authenticated. It then stores the association between refresh token and user as part of server side state so that it knows which refresh token was issued, whether it is still valid and for which user.

When the Client comes back to the Authorization Server with the refresh token later, the server can lookup the context and associated user from the server side storage.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I think I wasn't clear enough with the question. I didn't mean the Authorization Server, but the app that is using that Auth Server. Anyway, it turned out the tutorial was (as far as I know) wrong. I'll explain it in another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally it turned out that the tutorial I was following was wrong (at least on what it comes to the refresh tokens).

On the tutorial it said that Passport use the refresh tokens to send a request to the Auth Server to get a new access tokens. Well, that's not true. According to Jared Hanson, the author of Passport, Passport doesn't handle refresh tokens, that's something the backend of the applications have to handle if desired. Passport is just meant to make the first request to the Auth Server, when you get the access and refresh tokens. Then you can use refresh tokens to request new access tokens, for example using background tasks to check if any access token is going to expire anytime soon.

I think the one who wrote that tutorial was confused cause the second time you login with whatever strategy is available (Facebook, for example), the service doesn't ask for credentials, but that's not because of the refresh tokens, that's just cause the browser is saving the FB session. If you go to FB and logout, the next time you try to login in the app with FB, it will ask again for the credentials. In fact, if I'm not wrong, access and refresh tokens should be removed once a user logs out. Kind of surprising that you could find that kind of mistakes in a IBM developers blog.

BTW, Jared Hanson's comment about how Passport works (without using refresh tokens) can be found [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/34#issuecomment-6092923). Since is an old issue, I asked him myself on Twitter and the answer was just the same :)